# Opening txt file, Invalid literal for float()

Tags: python

Just trying to open this data set in txt format.

```
400.,41.7693
403.977686150861,42.68129270405837
408.3434392432695,43.86688321933424
412.61217560029104,45.59966935704514
416.4928450157652,48.72324436844505
420.9556148435605,51.64162102143182
423.86611690516617,53.534005882352936
427.0676691729323,56.2927838121295
431.43342226534077,59.73555626994983
435.31409168081495,60.85274733242134
439.291777831676,64.52351796625626
442.68736357021584,67.25949607843137
446.56803298569,68.92388276333789
450.73975260732476,71.29506379388965
454.7174387581858,72.41225485636114
458.21004123211253,73.68904464204286
462.4787775891341,75.5130300501596
466.6504972107689,76.72142038303693
470.2401164200825,77.72461235750114
473.73271889400917,78.63660506155951
477.61338830948335,79.57139758321932
481.9791414018918,80.64298901048792
```

When trying to open in...

```
with open('SunData.txt') as I:
    data = I.read()
data = data.split('\n')
WaveData = [float(row.split()[0]) for row in data]
IntData = [float(row.split()[1]) for row in data]
```

I'm returned with this error,

```
invalid literal for float(): 400.,41.7693
```

How do I correct this error?

Comment: Add a zero to 400. (i.e. 400.0) If this is the only case then it should work, if not you'll need a more creative solution.

Comment: There are commas in there which aren't part of a valid float. You could update your `split` call to also split on commas.

Answer (score 4):

Use `row.split(',')` to split on commas. `.split()` without passing arguments will only split on whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in data.split('\n'):
    floats = item.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really doing anything:

```
row.split()
```

Perhaps you meant

```
row.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the txt file, you can use the numpy library and the command : np.loadtxt()

Then you can make lots of processes because you get a numpy array ;)

```
import numpy as np

reading = np.loadtxt("SunData.txt", delimiter=',', usecols=(0, 1), unpack=True)

print reading
```

[image]

The documentation is there : [doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt)

Comment: numpy seems to be quite an overkill for this simple use case, doesn't it?

Comment: @k-nut Depends on the process after the data reading ;) At least, he gets a numpy array and he could make lots of processes

Comment: Given other questions by the OP, the data will be turned into a numpy array, so using numpy to read the data makes sense.